# Radio Button Unchecked mark didn't reduced using Java Mysql

Tags: java

I am creating a simple exam system in Java and Mysql. When I start the exam all the question displayed from the database successfully, if I read the question and answer it then click next button it will be moving to the next question. It is working fine. If the answer is clicked correctly marks added 1. unless unchecked the answer answer become 0 I want it. my problem is if I click correct answer on the radio button marks changes as one. The same question again I select as wrong answer it didn't changes 0, it still mark become 1. How to solve the problem I clear the radio buttons it won't clear. What I tried so far I attached below.

Click Correct answer . mark displayed 1 correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc6xE.jpg)

after that same question answer change as wrong answer. Mark displayed 
1.I need to display if we select wrong answer second time marks become decrement. I need to change as 1 become 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebfaO.jpg)

Code what tried so far I attached below.
Click the Answer

```
public void answercheck()
   { 
       String studentanswer="";
       if(r1.isSelected())
       {    
      if(r1.isSelected() == true)
       {
           studentanswer = r1.getText();
           r2.setSelected(false);
           r3.setSelected(false);
           r4.setSelected(false);
       }
        else
       {
           studentanswer="";
           r1.setSelected(false);
            r2.setSelected(true);
           r3.setSelected(true);
           r4.setSelected(true);
       }
       }

       else  if(r2.isSelected())
       {
        if(r2.isSelected() == true)
       {
           studentanswer = r2.getText();

           r1.setSelected(false);
           r3.setSelected(false);
           r4.setSelected(false);
       }

            else
       {
           studentanswer="";
           r2.setSelected(false);
           r1.setSelected(true);
           r3.setSelected(true);
           r4.setSelected(true);
       }
   }

       else  if(r3.isSelected())
       {
          if(r3.isSelected() == true)
          {
           studentanswer = r3.getText();
            r1.setSelected(false);
           r2.setSelected(false);
           r4.setSelected(false);
          }
          else
          {
                 studentanswer="";
                r3.setSelected(false);
                r1.setSelected(true);
                r2.setSelected(true);
                r4.setSelected(true);
          }
       }


      else  if(r4.isSelected())
       {
          if(r4.isSelected() == true)
          {
           studentanswer = r4.getText();
            r1.setSelected(false);
           r2.setSelected(false);
           r4.setSelected(false);
          }
          else
          {
                 studentanswer="";
                r4.setSelected(false);
                r1.setSelected(true);
                r2.setSelected(true);
                r4.setSelected(true);
          }
       }
      if(studentanswer.equals(answer))
       {

           marks = marks + 1;
           String marks1 = String.valueOf(marks);
           txtc.setText(marks1);

       }

 }
```

**Load all question from the database**

```
   public void Connection()
   {

        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineex","root","");
             stat = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
             rs = stat.executeQuery("select id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer from questions order by id DESC");

              while(rs.next())
            {     
                txtqu.setText(rs.getString("id"));
                txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
                r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
                r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
                r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
                r4.setText(rs.getString(6));
                 answer = rs.getString(7);
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        }

   }
```

**Next Click Button**

```
if(!rs.isFirst())
            {

            rs.previous();
             txtqu.setText(rs.getString("id"));
            txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
            r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
            r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
            r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
            r4.setText(rs.getString(6));
            answer = rs.getString(7);
            answercheck();
            }
```

**Previous Click Button**

```
if(!rs.isLast())
            {
                rs.next();
                txtqu.setText(rs.getString("id"));
                txtques.setText(rs.getString("question"));
                r1.setText(rs.getString(3));
                r2.setText(rs.getString(4));
                r3.setText(rs.getString(5));
                r4.setText(rs.getString(6));
                answer = rs.getString(7);

            }
```